# Query to find if a user is logged in to a PC, from a CSV Export

Tags: powershell, variables, export

Good evening!
I'll start by saying this is really not my forte so please be gentle. I am currently doing some work that requires me to remote to machines when there is nobody logged in. I can do this manually using the command 'QUERY USER /SERVER "HOSTNAME"' however this really is manual, and theres quite a delay when going one by one through a CSV. It's been OK to grab the odd straggler, but we're talking hundreds of machines here.

Outside of your basic query I don't have a great deal of PS experience, but I tried my best in a ForEach and just tried some googling as I came up against each error.

My export in question is a CSV file with the header of 'DeviceName' and all of the hostnames of each machine, nothing more.

Basically where I've got to is importing a CSV, and I can echo each of the hostnames, so I've tried a ForEach, run that same Command but despite googling I'm unable to get the foreach variable to pass through. I'm yet to get to a point where I'm even considering how I'll export this back out for review later.

What I'm basically asking for is any assistance to push me in the right direction to either make this work or an alternative that is staring me in the face. Thank you in advance!

> $1909 = Import-CSV C:\temp\1909-20221104.csv
>
> ```
> foreach( $DeviceName in $1909) {
>     cmd /c query user /server $DeviceName
> }
> ```

Comment: Try `foreach( $row in $1909) { query user /server $row.DeviceName }`. Since you're importing from a CSV file, you must refer to the column that contains the value via the corresponding property name. Also, there's no need to call via `cmd`.

Comment: Use $1909 | Format-Table to see current values and column names.